# MariaDB simple join with order by without temp table

Tags: query-optimization, mariadb

I have a job queue that is FIFO and can grow to the range of 0 to 10MM records. Each record has some value associated with a user. I have a second table that CAN contain USERS that have priority. This gets queried a lot by worker threads. This causes slow queries in the 1MM record range when ordering by this priority e.g.

```
select  *
    from  calcqueue
    LEFT JOIN  calc_priority USING(userId)
    where  calcqueue.isProcessing IS NULL
    order by  ISNULL(calc_priority.priority), calc_priority.priority
```

running explain on this gets me "`Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort`". I attempted to switch this over to a derived table which scales at larger number of rows, however I cant get the order to stay preserved which defeats the true intentions (but at least keeps my servers speedy)

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  priority,p,userId FROM
              ( SELECT  calc_priority.priority,
                        qt_uncalc.userId,
                        ISNULL(calc_priority.priority) p
                    from  
                      ( SELECT  userId
                            from  calcqueue
                            WHERE  isProcessing IS NULL
                      ) qt_uncalc
                    LEFT JOIN  calc_priority USING(userId) sortedQ
                    ORDER BY  p,sortedQ.priority ASC
              ) orderedT
```

Is there anyway to achieve this only using derived tables? calc_priority can (and does) change a lot. So adding the priority in at calcqueue insert time isn't an option

Comment: And you want all 10MM rows returned?  Perhaps there should be a `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan A**

Munch on this:

```
      ( SELECT  *, 999999 AS priority
            from  calcqueue
            LEFT JOIN  calc_priority USING(userId)
            where  calcqueue.isProcessing IS NULL
              AND  calc_priority.priority IS NULL
            LIMIT  10 
      )
    UNION  ALL
      ( SELECT  *, calc_priority.priority
            from  calcqueue
            JOIN  calc_priority USING(userId)
            where  calcqueue.isProcessing IS NULL
            ORDER BY  calc_priority.priority
            LIMIT  10 
      )
    ORDER BY  priority
```

and include

```
    LIMIT  10; INDEX(isProcessing, userId)
```

I'm attempting to avoid the hassle with `NULL`.

**Plan B**

You could change the app to always set `priority` to a suitable value, thereby avoid having to do the `UNION`.

Comment: I ended up doing plan B, but i'm wondering if i could test plan A.